# Launch command using app

Tags: macbook-pro, terminal, applications, macos, command-line

Could someone please tell me how to insert a terminal command into an "application" so when the app is clicked/opened the command is launched?

Comment: What is it, explicitly, that you're trying to accomplish?  There are several ways to do what you're asking, AppleScript, Automator or third-party Platypus.

Comment: um I'm trying to put an terminal command in an app so when open all the apps will open so my old computer won't work any more. pretty stupid way to crash it, but please don't judge

Comment: What is the actual command you're wanting to execute?

Comment: find /Applications -name \*.app -prune -exec open {} \;

Answer (score 1):

Instead of an application, you could always try writing a bash script.

To write and run a bash script, there are a few things to do:

1. Open TextEdit from `/Applications/Utilities/TextEdit.app` and then 
   press <kbd>shift</kbd><kbd>command</kbd><kbd>t</kbd> (⇧⌘T) to convert it into a plain text document.
2. Insert a *shebang* as the first line:

   `#!/bin/bash`
3. Add your command below it. In the end, your script should look like:

   `#!/bin/bash`
   `<your command here>`
   Then save the script.
4. In Terminal, do `chmod 775 /path/to/your/script`
5. To run your script, either click on the file (which should now have an executable icon).

Comment: For some reason SE doesn't allow me to escape the hash but interprets it as a title character. Thanks for pointing out the plaintext mistake.

Comment: I've made edits to have it show properly for you.

Answer (score 0):

Open **Automator** and choose **Application** for the document type.

Add a **Run Shell Script** *Action*.

Add your *command line* to the **Run Shell Script** *Action* so it's the only *command* in the *action*.

Save it as an **Application** to the desired location giving it whatever name you want.

[image]